# Mantener sesión abierta flutter sharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Buen día, en este momento estoy tratando de mantener mi sesión abierta de mi app con sharedpreferences, el problema es que al principio lo hizo pero después ya no guardo la preferencia del usuario, vi varios ejemplos y este código que estoy utilizando es el que les ha funcionado en otros lugares que consulte, pero si le doy hacia atrás a mi cel no respeta quedar dentro de la app, vuelve a mandarme al login, de ninguna forma me esta funcionando, agrego toda mi lógica del login por cualquier cosa:

main.dart:

```
 class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {

  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {

    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;

  
}
}


void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();

  final prefs = new UserPreferences();

  await prefs.initPrefs();

  runApp(MyApp());

}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final prefs = UserPreferences();

    return Provider(

      child: MaterialApp(
        home: prefs.usuario == null ? LoginPage() : HomePage(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Material App',
        initialRoute: '/login',
        routes: {
          '/login': (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
          '/home': (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
        },
        theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.orangeAccent[400]),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

login_page.dart:

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {

final userProvider = new UserProvider();
final _prefs = new UserPreferences();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return Scaffold(
   body: Stack(
     children: [
       _createFund(context),
       _loginForm(context),
     ],
   ),
 );
}


Widget _loginForm(BuildContext context) {

 //el context lo que hace es llamar el of que va a escalar hasta encontrar una instancia del provider
 //y buscar la intancia que se necesita
 final bloc = Provider.of(context);
 final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
 return SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
     children: [
       SafeArea(
         child: Container(
           height: 200.0,
         ),
       ),
       Container(
         width: size.width * 0.85,
         margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
         padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: Colors.white,
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
           boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
             BoxShadow(
                 color: Colors.black26,
                 blurRadius: 3.0,
                 offset: Offset(0.0, 5.0),
                 spreadRadius: 3.0)
           ],
         ),
         child: Column(
           children: [
             Text(
               'Ingreso',
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 60.0),
             _createEmail(bloc),
             SizedBox(
               height: 30.0,
             ),
             _createPassword(bloc),
             SizedBox(
               height: 30.0,
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 30.0,
             ),
             _createButtom(bloc),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ],
   ),
 );

}


Widget _createEmail(LoginBloc bloc) {

 //con el bloc se van a poder escuchar los cambios
 return StreamBuilder(
   stream: bloc.emailStream,
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
     return Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
       child: TextField(
         keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
         decoration: InputDecoration(
           icon: Icon(
             Icons.alternate_email,
             color: Colors.orangeAccent[400],
           ),
           hintText: 'ejemplo@correo.com',
           labelText: 'Correo electrónico',
           //counterText: snapshot.data,
           errorText: snapshot.error,
         ),
         onChanged: (value) => bloc.changeEmail(value),
         //o se puede utilizar bloc.changeEmail
       ),
     );
   },
 );

}


Widget _createPassword(LoginBloc bloc) {

 return StreamBuilder(
   stream: bloc.passwordStream,
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
     return Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
       child: TextField(
         obscureText: true,
         decoration: InputDecoration(
             icon: Icon(
               Icons.lock_outline,
               color: Colors.orangeAccent[400],
             ),
             labelText: 'Contraseña',
             //counterText: snapshot.data,
             errorText: snapshot.error),
         onChanged: bloc.changePassword,
       ),
     );
   },
 );

}


Widget _createButtom(LoginBloc bloc) {

 return StreamBuilder(
   stream: bloc.formValidStream,
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
     return RaisedButton(
       child: Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0, vertical: 15.0),
         child: Text('Ingresar'),
       ),
       shape:
           RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
       elevation: 0.0,
       color: Colors.orangeAccent[400],
       textColor: Colors.white,
       onPressed: snapshot.hasData ? () => _login(bloc, context) : null,
     );
   },
 );

}


//este metodo es para poder recuperar el último valor emitido en el formulario
_login(LoginBloc bloc, BuildContext context) async {

 Map info = await userProvider.login(bloc.email, bloc.password);
 if (info['ok']) {
   Navigator.push(
       context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
 } else {
   viewAlert(context, 'Información incorrecta');
 }

}


Widget _createFund(BuildContext context) {

 final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

 final fundGreen = Container(
   height: size.height * 0.4,
   width: double.infinity,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orangeAccent[400]),
 );

 return Stack(
   children: [
     fundGreen,
     Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
       child: Column(
         children: [
           Image(
             image: AssetImage('assets/img/logo.png'),
             width: 150.0,
           ),
           SizedBox(
             height: 10.0,
             width: double.infinity,
           ),
           Text(
             'By Fabilla',
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     )
   ],
 );

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

En el main no uses home, usa initialRoute

```
MaterialApp(
    // ...
    title: 'Material App',
    initialRoute: prefs.usuario == null ? '/login' : '/home',
    // ...
)
```

Ahora en tu login, en la parte donde usas el bloc cambia el código que tienes ahora por este:

```
  Map info = await userProvider.login(bloc.email, bloc.password);
    if (info['ok']) {
     Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('\home', (route) => false);
    } else {
      viewAlert(context, 'Información incorrecta');
  }
```

Y no veo en ninguna parte que estes guardando el valor de la respuesta de tu userProvider.login()

tienes que tener algo como esto:

```
_prefs.setString('usuario', info.usuario);
```

Si no guardas el valor del usuario jamas te va a funcionar, porque siempre sera null

Comment: el usuario si lo guardo tengo un archivo separado para los sharedpreferences, solo que no lo subí es algo así:   get usuario {
    return _prefs.getString('usuario') ?? '';
  }

  set usuario(String value) {
    _prefs.setString('usuario', value);
  }

Comment: Si era eso a lo que te referias con guardar el dato o era otra cosa?

Comment: Si a eso me referia, sigue sin funcionar a pesar de esos cambios?

Comment: Si sigue sin funcionar, si le doy hacia atrás con el botón del celular, termina saliendo de la app y me pide volver a ingresar la contraseña

Comment: Si funciono de la forma que me decías la verdad no sé que estaba fallando pero si es correcto como me sugeriste el código, mil gracias.

Comment: oye solo un problema la segunda parte de código me marca un error, en el Navigator: Unhandled Exception: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("home", null) in the _WidgetsAppState. y cuando corro la app siempre me inicia en el home en vez de login.

Comment: Pusiste en el Navigator que la ruta era "\home" en tu ejemplo lo tenias de esa forma, si solo pones el home 'home' de esta forma te va a dar error porque no existe esa ruta

Comment: Si lo pongo de esta forma  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/home', (route) => false); me marca un error: Unhandled Exception: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("home", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.  Y por este motivo lo cambie a: Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));, y aquí es cuando me da ese error que te comente.